# blazor wasm Dockerfile and dependencies problem

Tags: c#, docker, dockerfile

I developed a project using Blazor Webassembly (wasm) and created a Dockerfile. While everything is going well, the dockerfile file does not detect the SharedLibrary project I added for the project.

Would you help me with this topic ?

Dockerfile

```
    # Stage 1 - Build the Blazor WebAssembly app
    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
    WORKDIR /src



    COPY ../InventoryManagement.Frontend.csproj ../InventoryManagement.Frontend/
    COPY ../SharedLibrary.csproj ../Shared/SharedLibrary/


    # Restore the Blazor WebAssembly project
    RUN dotnet restore "src/InventoryManagement/Frontend/InventoryManagement.Frontend/InventoryManagement.Frontend.csproj"

    # Copy the entire project
    COPY . .

    WORKDIR "/src/src/InventoryManagement/Frontend/InventoryManagement.Frontend"

    # Build the Blazor WebAssembly project
    RUN dotnet build "InventoryManagement.Frontend.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

    # Stage 2 - Publish the Blazor WebAssembly app
    FROM build AS publish
    RUN dotnet publish "InventoryManagement.Frontend.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

    # Stage 3 - Create the Nginx container and copy the published app
    FROM nginx:latest AS final
    WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html

    # Copy the published app from the publish stage
    COPY --from=publish /app/publish/wwwroot .

    # Copy the custom nginx configuration
    #COPY . /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

    EXPOSE 80
    ENTRYPOINT ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Folder tree structure

```
    |   Inventory.sln
    |   
    \---src
        \---InventoryManagement
            +---Frontend
            |   \---InventoryManagement.Frontend
            |       |   App.razor
            |       |   Dockerfile
            |       |   InventoryManagement.Frontend.csproj
            |       |   InventoryManagement.Frontend.csproj.user
            |       |   Program.cs
            |       |   _Imports.razor
            |       |   
            |       +---Pages
            |       |       Counter.razor
            |       |       FetchData.razor
            |       |       Index.razor
            |       |       
            |       +---Properties
            |       |       launchSettings.json
            |       |       
            |       +---Shared
            |       |       MainLayout.razor
            |       |       MainLayout.razor.css
            |       |       NavMenu.razor
            |       |       NavMenu.razor.css
            |       |       SurveyPrompt.razor
            |       |       
            |       \---wwwroot
            |           |   favicon.png
            |           |   icon-192.png
            |           |   index.html
            |           |   
            |           +---css
            |           |   |   app.css
            |           |   |   
            |           |   +---bootstrap
            |           |   |       bootstrap.min.css
            |           |   |       bootstrap.min.css.map
            |           |   |       
            |           |   \---open-iconic
            |           |       |   FONT-LICENSE
            |           |       |   ICON-LICENSE
            |           |       |   README.md
            |           |       |   
            |           |       \---font
            |           |           +---css
            |           |           |       open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css
            |           |           |       
            |           |           \---fonts
            |           |                   open-iconic.eot
            |           |                   open-iconic.otf
            |           |                   open-iconic.svg
            |           |                   open-iconic.ttf
            |           |                   open-iconic.woff
            |           |                   
            |           \---sample-data
            |                   weather.json
            |                   
            \---Shared
                \---SharedLibrary
                        SharedLibrary.csproj
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I constantly get errors like the one below. I changed the SharedLibrary paths more than once, but I could not show the .csproj containing the SharedLibrary class.

[image]

.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="7.0.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="7.0.10" PrivateAssets="all" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\Shared\SharedLibrary\SharedLibrary.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

[image]

I removed "COPY ../SharedLibrary.csproj ../Shared/SharedLibrary/" but this time it gives the warning that SharedLibrary could not be found as in the picture.

Comment: The solutions mentioned below did not help me. I had already done research before. Many people mentioned that they could not find the Dockerfile even if they added the referenced classes in this way. I'm waiting for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is **SharedLibrary** a separate class library project and a dependency on your **InventoryManagement** project?

If so, you don't need to manually copy it. So remove the following line from your **Dockerfile** and it should work fine:

```
COPY ../SharedLibrary.csproj ../Shared/SharedLibrary/
```

Comment: Yes, I added it to a separate class and project as "dependency". I shared the content of the .csproj file above again.

Comment: Please confirm if the above solution works.